# Redirect url if string exists angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
var siteUrl = $location.path();
  var myUrl = siteUrl;
  var redirectUrl = siteUrl.substring(0, siteUrl.length-20);


  var isError = siteUrl.indexOf('somethingCharacter');
  if(isError) {
    $location.path(redirectUrl);
  }else{
    $location.path(siteUrl);
  }
```

I want to check if url exist with "somethingCharacter" it get redirect to redirecUrl what it make it does work well.

But when i refresh it redirect to login page can't understand why please suggest thank

Answer (score 0):

try routing see the sample code below

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../App/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })

    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: '../App/test.html',
        controller: 'testController'
    })
  .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
 }
```

in controller.js , modified your code a little

```
var isError = siteUrl.indexOf('somethingCharacter');
 if(isError) {
   location.href = redirectUrl;
  }else{
     location.href = siteUrl;
  }
```

try location.href or window.location instead of $location.path